# How to disable checkbox in a td if a particular checkbox is checked with the same name

Tags: jquery

```
<td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"  class="rows" style="text-align:center;"><input  name="activeloyalty" type="checkbox" value="24"></td>
<td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"  class="rows" style="text-align:center;"><input  name="activeloyalty" type="checkbox" value="24"></td>
<td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"  class="rows" style="text-align:center;"><input  name="activeloyalty" type="checkbox" value="24"></td>
<td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"  class="rows" style="text-align:center;"><input  name="activeloyalty" type="checkbox" value="24"></td>
<td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"  class="rows" style="text-align:center;"><input  name="activeloyalty" type="checkbox" value="24"></td>
<td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"  class="rows" style="text-align:center;"><input  name="activeloyalty" type="checkbox" value="24"></td>
<td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"  class="rows" style="text-align:center;"><input  name="activeloyalty" type="checkbox" value="24"></td>


$("[name=activeloyalty]")live('click', function () {
if($("[name=activeloyalty]").is(':checked') ){//how to uncheck the rest checkbox

}
});
```

I got a number of checkbox in a table,My question is when i check a particular checkbox ,how can i disable the rest checkbox ?

Comment: Wouldn't a radio button be the easier solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$("input[name=activeloyalty]").live('click', function () {
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('input[name="activeloyalty"]').not(':checked').attr('disabled', true);
   }
   else {
        $('input[name="activeloyalty"]').attr('disabled', false);
   }
});
```

Comment: it disables all the checkbox even the checked one? wont be able to uncheck it too

Comment: @dude: You did not mention that in your question but see updated answer :)

Comment: How to do the opposite if i uncheck that checkbox

Comment: @dude: No problem, have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name=activeloyalty]").change(function(){
    $("input[name=activeloyalty]").not(":checked").attr('disabled',true);
});
```